# Weird nil / not-nil behavior

Tags: go

I have the following code in my project:

```
        mod := srt.PrimaryModule()
        if mod != nil {
            mods[mod.Name()] = mod
        }
```

When it executes, I get:

```
PANIC: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
```

with the stack right at the third line of that.  (Yes it's the `mod` dereference, the map `mods` is created just a line above...)

So, when is a nil value not equal to nil?   And why?

```
 srt.PrimaryModule()
```

returns an interface type, `Module`, with a `Name()` method defined returning `string`.

In this particular case, `srt` is typed `StdReflectedType`, which is an interface type with a function `PrimaryModule()` returning type `Module`.   The actual implementation of `srt` is a struct that returns an uninitialized `Module` value from its fields.

Further, if I do

`reflect.ValueOf(mod)`

the result is the zero reflect.Value.

From the reflect package documentation:

```
 ValueOf returns a new Value initialized to the concrete value stored in the interface i. ValueOf(nil) returns the zero Value
```

Which seems right, except the previous line just determined `mod != nil`.   So what gives?

I cannot seem to reproduce this in a minimal example - is there any sensible behavior that could cause those lines to do this - am I not understandig something important about interface values and nil pointers?

Comment: perhaps mod.Name() is nil even though mod is not nil?

Comment: mod.Name() returns string.  It therefore cannot return nil.  Or did you mean the function?  If a zero-valued interface that is not nil can hold a nil implementation, how to check for that condition?

Comment: I don't know go, but I was just suspecting that there was something wrong with the LHS of the assignment.  perhaps mods is nil.  or mods[mod.Name()] is invalid to begin with.

Comment: See https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error for a likely explanation of what's going on. Show us the code for srt.PrimaryModule().

Comment: "An interface value is nil only if the inner value and type are both unset, (nil, nil)."   Ah, perfect.  TYVM, that's what I was missing!

Answer (score 2):

if any concrete value has been stored in the interface, the interface will not be `nil`. However, the concrete value stored in the interface can be a `nil` pointer.

For example, is the `fmt.Println(mod)` output, the concrete value, `nil`?

```
if mod != nil {
    fmt.Println(mod)
    mods[mod.Name()] = mod
}
```

Does `srt.PrimaryModule()` return a `nil` pointer to `mod`? If so, `mod.Name()` will `panic` with a `nil pointer dereference`.

References:

[The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec): [Interface types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Interface_types)

[Go Data Structures: Interfaces](http://research.swtch.com/interfaces)

[Why is my nil error value not equal to nil?](https://golang.org/doc/faq#nil_error)

---

What is the output from this revised version of your code?

```
mod := srt.PrimaryModule()
if mod != nil {
    fmt.Printf("%T %v\n", mod, mod)
    if mod.(Module) != nil {
        fmt.Println(mod.Name())
        mods[mod.Name()] = mod
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, last link is very helpful in particular.   Is there a way to explicitly check if the the concrete value is nil without knowing the concrete type?   Seems sketchy/no, since nils are typed - but would be nice if some reflect package method could do it (none seem to!)  My yucky workaround is just to have the Name() method of all implementing types bail out with a "" if the receiver is nil, and check for that also...

Comment: (InterfaceData(), perhaps?   But it's barely documented...)

Comment: (Or, you know, adding a func (m *Module) IsValid() bool { return m != nil } is much cleaner...)

Comment: @BadZen: See the question in my revised answer. Also, "The actual implementation of srt is a struct that returns an uninitialized Module value from its fields."  What do you mean exactly? What's missing is a good working example: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).